# replace class name using regular expression

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `classList.replace()` with regular expression. My goal is replacing an expression like **badge-something** with an other value like **badge-success**.

I've tried this:

```
element.classList.replace(/badge-*/i, 'badge-success')
```

But it returns **false** and doesn't change nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: `element.classList = element.classList.replace...`

Comment: @Clive That's wrong.

Comment: Is `classList` not a string? Fair enough then

Comment: @Clive no classList is a **list** and as it returns ```false``` it'd put className as ```false``` not as **badge-success**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a `DOMTokenList` (not a string).

[`DOMTokenList.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace) takes two strings, not a regex. The first argument is the exact class name you want to replace. Patterns are not supported.

If you want to use regexes, you need a string:

```
element.className = element.className.replace(/(^|\s)badge-\S+/g, '$1badge-success');
```

Answer (score 0):

classList.replace took string as an argument, so i think that is why it is not working.
But you can achieve your goal by twisting your code little bit,
repeat these steps

1. first took all className of that element(using element.className)
2. split those classes in array (using split function--- classname.split(' '))
3. apply forEach loop on array and by using str.search('badge-') > -1, replace that className using element.classList.replace..........Simple little long but code will work definitly

. 
Thank you